# What value, instead of the machine name, can I use in CREATE LOGIN statement to create a login from a local windows account

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, authentication

I am trying to automate the creation of logins from local Windows accounts within MS SQL using the CREATE LOGIN statement.

`CREATE LOGIN` requires that I pass the username in the "pre-Windows 2000" format of domainname\username. When creating a login for a local account (i.e. non-domain account), I must pass the machine name as the domain name.

However in certain cases, I will not know the machine name upfront so is there some type of well-known identifier I can use in place of the machine name? I have tried `.\<username>`, `(local)\<username>`, `(localhost)\<username>` etc. but these have not worked.

I have used an alternate approach of building the `CREATE LOGIN` text in a variable and passing this to sp_executesql which works fine as an alternative.

Any insight into a solution that avoids the sp_executesql is appreciated.

Comment: I think the only way to get client is via the `host_name()` function, and you can't call that inline in a `create login` to the best of my knowledge...  If you have a dynamic sql solution, I think you'll have to stick with it.

Comment: @JiggsJedi thank you for your comment, in the absence of any further information, it does seem that we have to work with sp_executesql.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE USER [BUILTIN\Administrators]
FOR LOGIN [BUILTIN\Administrators]
```